# Command "host 127.0.0.1" does not return localhost on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: localhost, hostname

Command "host 127.0.0.1" does not return localhost on Ubuntu 20.04.  Is it possible to have it return localhost like it does in Ubuntu 18.04?  We've got some tests that require this to work as it used to.

20.04:

```
root@ubuntu2004-x8664:~# host 127.0.0.1
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa has no PTR record
```

18.04:

```
root@ubuntu1804-x8664:~# host 127.0.0.1
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer localhost.
```

Thanks in advance.
Brendan

Comment: Does your `/etc/hosts` have a `127.0.0.1 localhost` line in it?

Comment: @waltinator Yes, the /etc/hosts file does have the 127.0.0.1 localhost entry.

Comment: @bkelley I am seeing the same thing you are seeing... But using host 127.X.X.!1 (literally ANY other IP in the 127. subnet other than 127.0.0.1) will return what you are seeking. Must be a change, a few googled questions are complaining about the same thing. Because this has little to no relevance (to me), someone else (smarter than me) can attempt to explain it, if the feeling compels them. (note the opposite on 18.04: using any other IP than 127.0.0.1 returns the error...... smells like a change)